# How to work with the session and display the data selection

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am working on a form that is sent to the external server, the results are sent back in the form of an array.

I need to display the data session is always performed last array data.

My code is as follows:

```
or($i=0; $i<count($item); $i++){

foreach($item[$i++] as $data) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $data['data_1'];
    $_SESSION['number'] = $data['data_2'];
    $_SESSION['price'] = $data['data_3'];
    echo "<br><table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Number</th><th>Price</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$_SESSION['id']."</td><td>".$_SESSION['number']."</td><td>".$_SESSION‌​['price']."</td><td><a href='page3.php'>Next</a></td></tr>";
    } 

echo "</table>";

}
```

Comment: for($i=0; $i<count($item); $i++){
    foreach($item[$i++] as $data)
 {
  $_SESSION['id'] = $data['data_1'];
  $_SESSION['number'] = $data['data_2'];
  $_SESSION['price'] = $data['data_3'];
     echo "<br><table border='1'>";
     echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Number</th><th>Price</th></tr>";  
  echo "<tr><td>".$_SESSION['id']."</td><td>".$_SESSION['number']."</td><td>".$_SESSION['price']."</td><td><a href='page3.php'>Next</a></td></tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";     
 }

Comment: Becuase u r assigning the value inside the loop

Comment: can give you an example right

Comment: Y u storing in session?

Comment: I do not save but needed when calling on other pages. I took from the array data CURL external server

Comment: Than it will only save the last value ...

Comment: I want to perform the appropriate value is selected

Comment: Test my given example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store them into SESSION than it will overwrite with the last SESSION value. Try this

```
echo " <table border='1'>";

foreach($item as $data) 
{ 
//$_SESSION['id'] = $data['data_1']; 
//$_SESSION['number'] = $data['data_2']; 
//$_SESSION['price'] = $data['data_3']; echo "<br>
"; 
echo "
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Number</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>"; 

echo "<tr>
<td>". $data['data_1'] ."</td>
<td>". $data['data_2'] ."</td>
<td>". $data['data_3'] ."</td>
<td><a href='page3.php'>Next</a>
</td></tr>"; 
}
echo "</table>";
```

**For session:**

Store `$item` into session as:

```
$_SESSION["item"] = $item;
```

And make sure you are using `session_start()` in all pages where you need session.